# How to set up routes in different languages in golang Revel framework?

Tags: go, multilingual, revel

in Node.js you can do something like `app.get("/:someroute(sign-in|anmelden)")` and you got yourself routes in different languages.

Can you do same in Golang Revel? Have routes defined like that with regex?
or some other way of supporting routes in different languages without having code redundancies?

```
GET     /login                                  App.Login
GET     /anmelden                               App.Login
```

this two to be actually one route?

Comment: It does not. You probably have to hack together your own router for this. But I should ask, why? This seems like it'd complicate your application unneccessarily and no modern web app I know does this.

Comment: I agree with @Gant. You should not do this. APIs are for computers to read. You should make the content multi-lingual, not the API routes.

Comment: Thank you guys. I give up on this approach. Stupid clients!